# How to Repel Otters from my Boathouse

Tags: pest-control

Otters are cute. What's not cute is the mess they leave when the come into my boathouse and use the deck (and anything laying on it) as a latrine. It smells like fish and urine. The otters must go.

Trapping or poisoning is not an option. I don't have a dog and don't plan to get one. I'm only at my cabin (with the boathouse) 2 weekends or so during the month.

Is there something I can put in the boathouse that will keep these cute pests from using my boathouse as an outhouse?

Comment: What about a door and some netting? Physically prevent them from entering.. Tarp?

Comment: Have you considered hanging a huge plastic owl? I see those hanging in the boathouses on the lake by our home quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moth Balls

I read some hints about strong smells repelling otters and other pests. Since I would rather not have to harvest coyote urine, I chose to try moth balls in the form of those packs that can be hung in a closet:

[image: Moth Cake closet repellent]

So far, so good. After 2 weeks with 3 of these hanging in the boathouse (which is closed except for the area below the front door), no more scat on the deck.